# What art exists about classification of monoids?

Tags: monoid

For groups, there is a solid foundation to classify them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups

What art exists for monoids?

Comment: Work has been done, but monoids and semigroups are MUCH more complicated than groups. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116908/655547) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/131110/145247) for some references. There are lots of deep connections to formal language theory and automata, so you might also want to look in those kinds of references to get a taste of how complicated things can be.

Comment: Thank you! Partially.

Comment: I guess to start, how about commutative semigroups?